VisionOS and On-Demand resources
I have a project where I would like to use on-demand resources for some of my RealityComposer assets.
I excluded Apple ODR solution because of the 4GB limit and also because apparently it doesn't support .rkasset. Also from the RealityComposerPro package it seems it is not possible to add tags.
Maybe because it is a static library.
So I am thinking to bundle the assets into .bundle, upload it into a server and download it from the client when it is needed into a document folder. And access it on request.
The problem:
Apple suggests to use the compiled assets from .rkassets for performances reasons. Once they are compiled they are in a .reality archive inside the package bundle.
So what could be a nice scalable solution to build the Reality Composer package, extract the bundle with the .reality archive, and upload it into a private hosting server.
Also how would you structure your repo to maintain this?

This section of Apple's On-Demand Resources Guide seems to outline a workflow that you could use.
